# Frozen game and broken build

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a Minecraft world and built a volcano which I was quite happy with. Then I tried to use a command block to create flame particles on top of it, just for a finishing touch. I used the command `/particle flame coordinates coordinates2 0.5 300000`. I set the command block to always active and repeat, which was an absolutely pathetic idea. The world froze completely. I thought maybe I could change the version of the game to 1.9, as repeat CBs weren't implemented yet, then. When I logged in, everything was fine, other than the fact that a whole chunk of the build was gone, just gone. I did some research and I found out that I could use NBTExplorer to disable command blocks, and I did so. When I logged on my 1.11 user, the world was still in 1.9, and the chunk was missing. I quit the world and relogged, and it said that the world was in 1.11, but the chunk was still gone.

Firstly, what in the world have I done? Secondly, what can I do, if anything, to fix my slightly embarrassing problem?

Comment: Did you take a backup before loading the world in an older version? You should have seen [this message](http://i.imgur.com/6ReHTfN.png) when attempting to load the world in 1.9.

Comment: Nope, I did not. I never got that message... Weird...

Answer (score 1):

Yep...the build is gone, from what you said. If I remember correctly, same happened to moi.

My reason it's lost : Exiting the game requires saving, no matter what (unless you crash or force quit, etc) You saved the world with the chunk not there.

I don't believe you can get it back, but i recommend using mcedit, as that will read the files in the mc folder and hopefully read the "missing" chunks, ***if it is still there.***